# How to replace javascript array with php array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have this javascript array

```
   <script>
$(function() {
 var foo= [ "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "one",
            "final"];
</script>
```

Now, I am trying to replace the `foo` with a PHP array.

```
<?php $array = array("sky","mac","rain","bob","sep","ion"); ?>
```

Now, **I tried**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
     var foo= [<?php array("sky","mac","rain","bob","sep","ion"); ?> ];
    </script>
```

But, it seems not to be working

Comment: You forgot `echo`ing the array's content?!

Comment: You can't just echo an array.

Comment: This is the ideal use case for the [`json_encode`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IN PHP you can use the method [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert most PHP arrays into JSON, which is a legit object in JavaScript.

```
<?php $array = array("sky","mac","rain","bob","sep","ion"); ?>

<script>
// ...
var foo = <?php echo json_encode( $array ); ?>;
// ...
</script>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this rather than the previous answer? @Sirko

Comment: See my comment below the previous answer.

Comment: @Simon Less verbose. Usage of a built-in-method almost always is better than reinventing the wheel. The same command can be used to transfer multi-level-arrays / objects. ...

Comment: @Sirko thanks, I've learned a new thing today. But, the I wanted to use this code for another project, and got another problem. I guess I'll ask a new question. Help if you can pls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo= ['<?php print implode("','", array("sky","mac","rain","bob","sep","ion")); ?>'];
```

Comment: This does not guarantee the values being properly escaped/encoded for JavaScript. json_encode() should be used in stead as suggested in the other answer

Comment: For example, if the PHP array contains `'`, rest of the JavaScript will me messed up.